# Switch statement inside a foreach loop - not getting expected results

Tags: c#, foreach, switch-statement

So I am trying to loop though items that are in a listbox in my application. The list box will allow you to select multiple items to which I have a method tied to each item in the listbox. I have a counter variable incremented each time the loop works.When I use the foreach loop with the switch statement below, it does the first item correct, but then loops through the same item again. I know I am missing something as it is supposed to go to the next item in the listbox and not the same item.

```
      string reportname = lstbxReports.SelectedValue.ToString();
      int i = 0;
            foreach (var report in reportname)
            {
                switch (reportname)
                {
                    case "Overview":
                        {
                            if (i < 1)
                            {
                                PrintOverview(filename);
                            }
                            else if (i >= 1)
                            {
                                PrintOverviewAppend(filename);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Sources":
                        {
                            if (i < 1)
                            {
                             PrintSource(filename);
                            }
                            else if (i >= 1) 
                            {
                             PrintSourceAppend(filename);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                       }
                      i++
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how I can get the foreach loop to go to the next item in the selected listbox?

Also, this is just a snippet as I have about 11 case items to loop through.

Comment: `switch (reportname)`? `foreach (var report in reportname)`? is correct?

Comment: When you hover over the `var` in the `foreach`, you'll see that `report` is `char` (`reportname` is a string, and iterating a string gives you a collection of chars) - I'm assuming that's not what you want to do. Just something to watch out for, making sure you are iterating over the right collection whenever you `foreach` over something.

Comment: If you're gonna have a fixed set of "reportname"s, then I'd suggest using an `Enum` for that. Less error prone, more readable, easier to `switch` on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(string item in listBox.Items)
{
}
```

?

Depends on how you setup the data source for the listbox though (I'm assuming this is WinForm?). If you created it by adding .Items or using the designer then this will work. However if you've used .DataSource then it wont work.

I'd personally have a

```
List<string> list = SomeMethodWhereIMakeTheList();
```

and set that to:

```
listbox.DataSource = list;
```

then I wouldn't even have to touch the ListBox to mess with the contents:

```
list.ForEach(...)
```

Comment: Ah.. Yes, this is what I have going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to switch on `report`, not `reportname`.

Comment: Maybe it's `foreach (var reportname in report)`?

Comment: That would probably make more sense.

Comment: Reportname is the string that holds the selected item in the listbox. If I try to change it around it will not work, for me. HA

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the print logic in a foreach. Split out the data then print such this (*note I changed the name of reportname to reportnames to signify a list of items*)

```
string reportnames = lstbxReports.SelectedValue.ToString();

var firstReport = reportnames.First(); // No error checking here, would use FirstOrDefault with null checks.

if (firstReport == "OverView")
   PrintOverview(filename);
else
   PrintSource(filename);

// Now print out the rest
reportnames.Skip(1)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(rp =>
{
   if (rp == "OverView")
      PrintOverviewAppend(filename);
   else
      PrintSourceAppend(filename);
});
```